# iOS 8 - Is it possible to select existing keyboards?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have some language apps that require people entering text in a couple of languages. For example, one screen requires english text and another, french.

I am learning how to create custom keyboards as keyboard extensions. But all I'm doing is recreating existing keyboards, like QWERTY, AZERTY, etc.

Is there now a way to select a specific language keyboard depending upon what class is being used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Add Keyboard into your want Preffereed language or  country.. 
From

```
Menu >> Setting >> Genral >> KeyBoard >> Keyboards >> Add New Keyboard
```

And Add It to what type of keyboard do you want...

and switch it to .. world (or Circle) icon on keyboard .. to one to another...

Comment: I think the OP means change it programmatically, not make the user change it.

Comment: @Thedude - exactly. To have a user have to switch keyboards for each screen, is a bit tedious, and usually, people start typing incorrectly before realizing they are in the wrong language..